# Softwares and lib files

Tags: package-management, software-sources

I have been using `suse` until now. I am trying to learn Ubuntu and I need to install some packages and library files but I could not find some (maybe due to they are named different from `suse`).

For example typing `apt-cache compat` gives no results and also `glibc`, `cross` and needed 32-bit libraries. Is there any way to see packages and library lists on Ubuntu like `opensuse`?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to find a Ubuntu package:

- Use https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/ to find the package via a browser.
- Use **Ubuntu Software center** and search for the package you are looking for. Ubuntu Software center is shipped by default with Ubuntu.

  or
- Use `gnome-terminal` and type `apt-cache policy` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to list down the packages available in the repository.

Hope this helps.